# Set Theory, Universal Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If I have two sets A and B, given that $A := \{1, 4, 9, 16\}$ and $B := \{1, 8, 27\}$. Then is it correct to assume that the universal set is $U := \{1, 2, 3, ..., 27\}$?

Another thing, since the difference of two sets $A$ and $B$ is $A \cap B^c$, is $\mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(B) = \mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B)^c$ or $\mathcal{P}(A) \cap \mathcal{P}(B^c)$? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the context. Usually the universal set is made clear beforehand. As for the second question, the former is true. Maybe it's a bit more clear if you set $C := \mathcal{P}(A)$ and $D := \mathcal{P}(B)$. Now apply the definition of $C - D$ and afterwards, just 'remember' *what* $C$ and $D$ where.

As a side note, I'd assume the universal set here is $\mathbb{N}_0$, but really there is no way to know without more information on what you're working with.

Comment: I am given with just the two sets A and B. And I needed to work on the complement of A so I assumed I need a universal set. I also need to  list down the elements of P(B-A) and P(B)-P(A).

Comment: I see. If no context is provided, you will have to choose a universal set (and clearly state it before you proceed). Are you sure there's no contextual information that indicates a certain universal set? Sometimes this is assumed from the definition of the sets, e.g if I say "let $X,Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}$" with no additional information, you will assume $\mathbb{R}$ is the universal set here.

Comment: The problem is "Given the sets A={1, 4, 9, 16} and B={1, 8, 27}. Determine the sets in P(B-A) and P(B)-P(A)."

Comment: @frstrtdmthmtcn: Why do you need a universal set for that?

Comment: To get the complement of P(A). Is it wrong?

Comment: @frstrtdmthmtcn: Why do you need the complement of anything here? You have set difference, there is no complements being mentioned.

Comment: You don't need the complement of P(A).... just the sets in P(B) that are not in P(A).

Comment: It is true that $A - B = A\cap B^c$ but you don't actually need to know what $B^c$ is to calculate this.  You only need the elements not in B that are in A.

Comment: More useful would be $A- B = A - (A\cap B)$.

Comment: The thing about complements is that most of the time you are not supposed to actually calculate them.  You are just supposed to classify them as everything that is not.  Intuitively, I think of the Universal set as absolutely everything possibly imaginable or not in the real or conceptual universe.  Which would make $A^c$ ridiculous impossible to list.  But that's fine as it's just everything that *isn't* in A.  So $B- A = B \cap A^c$ is just, everything in B that is not in A.  I don't consider *anything* that's not in B.

Comment: "To get the complement of P(A). Is it wrong?"  $P(B) - P(A) = P(B) \cap P(A)^c \subset P(B)$ you only need to find the complement of $P(A)$ *restricted to the elements of $P(B)$*.

Answer (score 0):

"Then is it correct to assume that the universal set is U = {1, 2, 3, ..., 27}?"

The only thing you can know for certain is $\{1,4,8,9,16, 27\} \subseteq U$.  But you don't need to know what the universal set is most of the time.  If unstated it probably is simply anything that is conceivable.

.....

hmmm... $P(A) - P(B)$ are all the subset of $A$ that are not subsets of $B$.

That is $P(A) \cap P(B)^c$.

$P(B^c)$ and $P(B)^c$ are not the same. The former is the subsets of elements not in $B$ and the latter is everything that is not a subset of $B$. $P(B^c) \subset P(B)^c$ but $P(B)^c \not \subset P(B^c)$.

Example: if $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B= \{2,3,4\}$ and let the universal set $U = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

$P(A) - P(B) = \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$

$P(B)^c = $ anything that isn't a subset of $B$ which if our universal set is the subsets of $U$ is everything that has $1$  or $5$ as an element.

$P(B^c) = P (\{1, 5\}) = \{\emptyset, \{1\},\{5\},\{1,5\}\}$

$P(A) \cap P(B)^c = P(A) - P(B)$ but $P(A) \cap P(B)^c =\{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$.

=======

In a comment in the other answer you wrote that the original problem is "The problem is "Given the sets A={1, 4, 9, 16} and B={1, 8, 27}. Determine the sets in P(B-A) and P(B)-P(A)"

Since $B- A = \{8,27\}$ the $P(B-A)$ are the subsets of $\{8,27\}$. i.e $\{\emptyset, \{8\},\{27\}, \{8,27\}\}$.

$P(B)$ are the $2^3 = 8$ subsets of $B$.  $\{\emptyset, \{8\},\{27\}, \{8,27\}, \{1\},\{1,8\},\{1,27\}, \{1,8,27\}\}$

$P(A)$ are the subsets of $A$.  I'm not going to list them. There are $2^{4} =16$ of them.  But

$P(B) - P(A)$ are the subsets of $B$ that are not subsets of $A$. As $B$ and $A$ have only the element $1$ in common, the only subsets that have in common are $\emptyset$ and $\{1\}$. So those are removed from $P(B)$.

So $P(B) - P(A) =  ${ {8},{27}, {8,27},{1,8},{1,27}, {1,8,27}}$

Comment: What if I have sets A and B and the universal set U. If I get the complement of A x B, should I use U x U as basis?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$, $B$, $U$, and $U^{'}$ be four sets satisfying

$\quad A \cup B \subset U$

and

$\quad A \cup B \subset U^{'}$

Then $A \cap B^c = A \cap B^{c^{'}}$, where $^c$ (resp. $^{c^{'}}$  is the complement in $U$ (resp. $U^{'}$).

So if you have only one definition for the set difference operation, and no indication for the universal set, simply set the context yourself and let $U = A \cup B$, defining the universal set to be the minimal set containing both $A$ and $B$.